# How to transform unstructured xml from to structured xml using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, transformation

**How to transform unstructured xml from to structured & required form using Xquery,  appreciate the quick help**.

Input XML file with Section as root node.

```
<Section>
<LowerAlpha>a</LowerAlpha>
<Number>1</Number>
<LowerAlpha>b</LowerAlpha>
<Number>1</Number>
<Roman>i</Roman>
<UpperAlpha>A</UpperAlpha>
<UpperAlpha>B</UpperAlpha>
<UpperAlpha>C</UpperAlpha>
<Roman>ii</Roman>
<Roman>iii</Roman>
<Number>2</Number>
<Number>3</Number>
<LowerAlpha>c</LowerAlpha>
<Number>1</Number>
<Number>2</Number>
<Roman>i</Roman>
</Section>
```

output xml file (Section -> LowerAlpha -> Number -> Roman -> UpperAlpha and data wrapped with in value tag.)

```
<Section>
<LowerAlpha>
<value>a</value>
<Number><value>1</value></Number>
</LowerAlpha>
<LowerAlpha>
<value>b</value>
<Number>
<value>1</value>
<Roman>
<value>i</value>
<UpperAlpha><value>A</value></UpperAlpha>
<UpperAlpha><value>B</value></UpperAlpha>
<UpperAlpha><value>C</value></UpperAlpha>
</Roman>
<Roman><value>ii</value></Roman>
<Roman><value>iii</value></Roman>
</Number>
<Number>2</Number>
<Number>3</Number>
</LowerAlpha>
<LowerAlpha><value>c</value>
<Number><value>1</value></Number>
<Number><value>2</value>
<Roman><value>i</value></Roman>
</Number>
</LowerAlpha>
</Section>
```

Comment: I think you need to be more explicit about what rules you want followed for changing the former to the latter. It looks like each <Number> is supposed to pull in everything following it until the next Number, and maybe likewise for LowerAlpha; I'm not sure about whether that's also supposed to be true of Roman since you didn't provide an example of that.

(I'm more fluent in XSLT than XQuery, but they're closely related to each other.)

Comment: There are some inconsistencies in your example output - namely `<Number>2</Number>` and `<Number>3</Number>`, which I assume are wrong. I have corrected them in my answer to be `<Number><value>2</value></Number>` and `<Number><value>3</value></Number>`. Please update the question if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion. The solution has some similarities to XSLT, but with added logic to follow the nesting rules specific to your application. However, it should be generic enough to adapt to additional nesting rules:

```
declare function local:passthru(
    $e as element(),
    $restrict as xs:QName*
) {
    element { node-name($e) } {
        for $n in $e/*[if (exists($restrict)) then 
          node-name(.) = $restrict else true()]
        return local:process($n)
    }
};

declare function local:value-wrap(
    $e as element()
) {
    element { node-name($e) } {
        element value {
            $e/node()
        }
    }
};

declare function local:nest(
  $e as element(),
  $restrict as xs:QName*
)
{
  element { node-name($e) } {
    element value { $e/string() },
    let $next := ($e/following-sibling::*[node-name(.) eq node-name($e)])[1]
    let $children := document{ $e/following-sibling::*[ 
      if (empty($next)) then true() else . << $next] }/*
    for $c in $children[if (exists($restrict)) then 
      node-name(.) = $restrict else true()]
    return local:process($c)
  }
};

declare function local:process( 
    $e as item() 
) as item()?
{
    typeswitch ($e) 
        case element(Section) return local:passthru($e, xs:QName('LowerAlpha'))
        case element(Number) return local:nest($e, (xs:QName('Roman'))) 
        case element(LowerAlpha) return local:nest($e, xs:QName('Number'))
        case element(Roman) return local:nest($e, xs:QName('UpperAlpha'))
        case element(UpperAlpha) return local:value-wrap($e)
        default return ()
};

local:process(**Input XML**)
```

Output:

```
<Section>
    <LowerAlpha>
        <value>a</value>
        <Number>
            <value>1</value>
        </Number>
    </LowerAlpha>
    <LowerAlpha>
        <value>b</value>
        <Number>
            <value>1</value>
            <Roman>
                <value>i</value>
                <UpperAlpha>
                    <value>A</value>
                </UpperAlpha>
                <UpperAlpha>
                    <value>B</value>
                </UpperAlpha>
                <UpperAlpha>
                    <value>C</value>
                </UpperAlpha>
            </Roman>
            <Roman>
                <value>ii</value>
            </Roman>
            <Roman>
                <value>iii</value>
            </Roman>
        </Number>
        <Number>
            <value>2</value>
        </Number>
        <Number>
            <value>3</value>
        </Number>
    </LowerAlpha>
    <LowerAlpha>
        <value>c</value>
        <Number>
            <value>1</value>
        </Number>
        <Number>
            <value>2</value>
            <Roman>
                <value>i</value>
            </Roman>
        </Number>
    </LowerAlpha>
</Section>
```